# Install Rails 6 - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem actionpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

We want to prepare our app for Rails 6.

```
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', tag: 'v6.0.0.beta2'
```

I ran `bundle install`.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails was resolved to 6.0.0.beta2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 6.0.0.beta2)

    rails-controller-testing was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.x)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

    sprockets-rails (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
```

Not sure how exactly to go forward (should I comment out all gems which are listed as problematic? It seems to me that all dependencies are are using `>=` operator - doesn't this mean that actionpack (= 6.0.0.beta2) should be OK too? Can I get some guidance?

Comment: One thing to try is bundle update first. I believe if this is not a clean install, the gems you already have installed may be conflicting which is the dependency issues you see here. I'm not entirely confident in that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I invested more time into this and learned how to solve those issues. I am pretty sure that I didn't post most important part of the output about dependencies.

Normally there are gems which are locked to some gem versions. You want to find them manually via output. Be careful about output like this:

```
 gem_xyz was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (< 3.0)
```

Then you can check whether there is a fix on specific Github branch for e.g. Rails 6 version and use the gem directly from that branch. Not super easy but you can go forward slowly and prepare you project to be Rails6 a little bit earlier ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to test 6.0.0.rc2. I solved by removing the gem `minitest-rails-capybara` from the `Gemfile` and by improving system tests according to 
 https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with actionpack but the other gems you are trying to install, the versions are not compactible with actionpack (= 6.0.0.beta2)

```
rails-controller-testing was resolved to 1.0.4

rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.2

sprockets-rails (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.1
```

You need to find versions that are compactible with the version of your actionpack. The version of actionpack is determined by the version of rails you are using. I had similar experience with

```
  rspec-rails (~>3.4.2) and,
  factory_girl_rails (~>1.0.4)
```

Upgrading both resolves the issue.